# Share data by key-chain group access between two apps created by two different apple developer account?

Tags: ios

My scenario is:
1) I have an developer account, which creates apps shown in app store.
2) Meanwhile, I have another enterprise account which joins the enterprise program, and is for creating apps used in my company.
I would like the second app to use data from the first app, for some internal advanced feature.
I know I could build a different package for the first app, using my enterprise provision file. However, it would be better if all the employees can use the real markeing version app, so they can help to test the real one.

My question is:
Is it possible to have my two apps (under two different apple developer account) share data?

P.S. I've read this article http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html and I understand that the keychain group access should between apps with the same bundle seed ID. I sent this question just in wonder if there is anything I can do differently, as I own the two different account?

P.P.S. 
I've also considered other options like pasteboard and openURL with specific URL scheme. If finally I found I cannot use key chain approach, I will use pasteboard instead. But I would like to know if the key chain approach is possible first.

Comment: Are asking if the data can sit in one spot while both apps access the same files or are you looking for a way to transfer data between the two apps?

Comment: Yes, of course your two apps can share data, depending on implementation. You can share the data via a web server if you have one.

Comment: @rmaddy transfer data between the two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html), it can share data between apps, but you'll have to launch one app, have it write to the pasteboard and then switch to the other app and have it pull out the data.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will fallback to use UIPasteboard if finally I found it's impossible to use key chain access for my scenario.

Comment: I've researched sharing data for an internal app and I couldn't find anything other than UIPasteboard.  Hopefully you'll find somethig, good luck!